# cypress open --config baseUrl=https://... won't open

Tags: windows, cmd, cypress

I can't manage to open cypress in my windows machine (this is the CI environment) when I pass --config:

1. In cmd.exe, if I type `npx cypress open` cypress opens just fine;
2. If I instead type `npx cypress open --config baseUrl=https://...` then nothing appears and the command terminates without printing anything in the terminal.

In the second case, `echo %errorlevel%` prints 0.

I can reproduce the problem with `cypress run`: passing a `--config baseUrl=...` parameter breaks it.

I'm using cypress package and binary 3.6.0. `cypress verify` is happy.

Comment: Looks like it's being tracked here https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regression is now fixed in [Cypress 3.8.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#3-8-0) <sup>(h/t to [Robert DROP TABLE STUDENTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8340320/robert-drop-table-students)).</sup>

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

It's a regression introduced in 3.5.0 which came bundled with new Electron, where the underlying issue seems to be this PR: [electron/electron#13039](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/13039) (h/t [Jennifer Sheane](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5466#issuecomment-547123860)), which is [fixing a security issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13226#issuecomment-397973671) and is unlikely to be reverted/handled differently any time soon.

It's being tracked in [cypress shows error in Windows when passing args containing a url in 3.5.0](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5466).

Comment: it is fixed in Cypress 3.8.0